# Examine the continuity of function $f(x)=\frac{2x^2-4x}{|x+1|+|x-3|-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, absolute-value

Using the definition of absolute value for
$$|x+1|=\begin{cases}
x+1, & x\ge -1\\
-x-1, & x>-1
\end{cases}$$
and
$$|x-3|=\begin{cases}
x-3, & x\ge 3\\
-x+3, & x>3
\end{cases}$$
and checking cases when $$x<0,x=0,x>0$$
I get this definition of a function $f(x)$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
3, & x=3,x=-1\\
x(x-2), & x>0\\
0, & x=0\\
2-x, & x<0
\end{cases}$$

Is this definition of a function $f(x)$ correct, and if not what is wrong?

Comment: How does it come that the turning points of your function do not comprehend $-1$ nor $3$?
You should really break down the real lines into a sequence of domains bounded respectively by: $-\infty ; -1, 3 ; +\infty$ (i.e $\mathbb{R}= ]-\infty , -1[\cup [-1,3[ \cup [3, \infty[$) and see what happens when you take $x$ in between each pair of these

Comment: @ b00n heT  I can't determine the value on that domain, any help?

Comment: you are not supposed to determine **the value**. You are supposed to write what the function looks like. For example taking the function $f(x)=|x+1|$ as you did above, leads to the above case division.
In simple words you just need to check if what sits inside the absolute value is positive or negative in that region (any test value will do). If it is positive, replace the $|\dots|$ with simple brackets $(\dots)$; if negative, replace $|\dots|$ with $-(\dots)$.

Comment: What is your actual question: the one in your title (is $f(x)$ continuous?), or the one at the end of your post (is this definition of $f(x)$ correct?)?

Comment: @Rory Daulton  If I know the definition of a function with cases, than it is easy to rxamine continuity. I am interested in the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: Then you should change the title of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|x+1|=\begin{cases}
x+1& x\ge -1\\
-x-1, & x\color{red}<-1
\end{cases}$$
and
$$|x-3|=\begin{cases}
x-3, & x\ge 3\\
-x+3, & x\color{red}<3
\end{cases}$$